# I made a mistake using regex (.*) to find and replace in Notepad++ and need to undo it

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm editing websites for hotels around the country and I'm using Notepad++ (NPP). Our sites contain a text string along the lines of "Book a London hotel", although with different cities where you see London in this string. There are about 30 cities.

I wanted to change the word "a" to "the" for every site, so attempted a find and replace with `(.*)`

In the NPP find and replace section, I selected the regular expression search mode, then I wrote "book a `(.*)` hotel" in the find section and "book the `(.*)` hotel" in the replace section.

While the find and replace identified the correct strings, the result was that the characters `(.*)` appeared in the replaced strings rather than the unique city name! Fail!

Fortunately, the full line says, "Visiting London? Book a London hotel." so I haven't completely lost the city name and I think this can be corrected.

Would anyone be able to help me here? I need to know the exact regex to put in the find and replace fields to edit the text, but keep the unique city name for each of the sites.

I hope this is clear. Please do not hesitate to ask if I can provide any further clarification.

Comment: By the way, I'm attempting to have a go at this myself, and am wondering if the () and \1 could help...

Comment: don't use regex option and replace `(.*)` with `the`

Comment: Have you tried CTRL+Z? :P

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Visiting (.+)\? Book the \(\*\) hotel` with `Visiting \1? Book the \1 hotel`.

Answer (score 1):

To fix, use [this expression](http://regex101.com/r/cC2vD2):

```
Visiting (.*?)[?] Book the \(\.\*\) hotel[.]
Visiting \1? Book the \1 hotel.
```

To do what you wanted initially, use [this expression](http://regex101.com/r/iN3vH3):

```
Book a (.*?) hotel
Book the \1 hotel
```

---

Note, first of all, that I use `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)` which does a [lazy match instead of greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy).  This will prevent your expression from chewing up your whole string.  To replace with a [captured group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) use `\1`, `\2`, etc.

`\(\.\*\)` will match `(.*)` literally.  Each character needs to be escaped with `\` since they are all reserved.  I also put `?` and `.` in character classes (`[?]` and `[.]`), you can also escape these if you want (`\?` and `\.`) I just think the character class looks cleaner.

Comment: The parentheses will not appear if he replaced with `(.*)`

Comment: @hwnd [are you sure](http://regex101.com/r/gW3cO7)? Doesn't replace just replace with a plain text string (except for captured references).

Comment: Interesting, wonder if that is something with N++.  If that's the case, you'll just replace `\(\.\*\)` with `\.\*`.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help everyone. I got it sorted in the end using the greedy match and the captured group options.